# How to implement tab windows like Google Chrome for mac using cocoa objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, google-chrome

I have once stumbled upon an open source project that implements the Google Chrome like tab feature in cocoa objective-c for mac. I have since forgot where to find it, or what its called. Anyone have any suggestions?

Here is what I'm looking for.
[image]

Comment: This one maybe? https://github.com/splicer/psmtabbarcontrol

Comment: I believe you're looking for Chromium Tabs. https://github.com/rsms/chromium-tabs

Comment: I'm glad you found it before the impending close. It looks good, and I'm going to bookmark the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Wekwa said, Chrome uses [Chromium Tabs](https://github.com/rsms/chromium-tabs).